# Stop QGIS from printing true in python console when updating records

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

How can I stop QGIS from printing `True` twice in python console for each updated record? This is slowing down the calculations.

Example:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
with edit(layer):
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        if feature['Randint'] % 2 == 0:
            new_value =  'Even'
        else:
            new_value = 'Odd'
        feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('Parity'), new_value)
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

True*10000:
[image]

Comment: simple workaround, change last line to `_ = layer.updateFeature(feature)` and the same for setAttribute `_ = feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('Parity'), new_value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions [setAttribute](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#a0075d1f9c830d62c8fda6b843c307dd8) and [updateFeature](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a9334033354a994132b28fcd1700b64e3) both return a boolean (indicating whether or not the operation was successful).
Since you are executing from the terminal, if you do not use this returned value, the value will return to the console, that is why assigning it to a variable result in it not being printed anymore.

For example:

```
_ = feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('Parity'), new_value)
_ = layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

Note that the variable name does not need to be an underscore, I used it because I believe it makes clear that it is a variable that has no use for the script itself.

And, as the OP mentioned in the comment, [print statements make things a lot slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288185/performance-effect-of-using-print-statements-in-python-script)